# Events of WPF behaviors in DesignMode

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

I have a problem with my behavior using Microsoft Expression Blend. I don't know how to get the OnAttached event in Expression Blend or Visual Studio. It doesn't fire. Here's an example:

```
public class MyBehavior : Behavior<Path>
{
    public PathNavigation()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        // Only firing in runtime
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Only firing in runtime
    }
}
```

Is there a possibility to get that events while designing in Blend?
Thanks in advance.
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that at design time, `AssociatedObject.IsLoaded == true`? You could check that before attaching your event handler, and call a common `OnLoaded` method.

Comment: I don't know, but even if it is true... Why can't I get the OnAttached-event?

Comment: Sorry, I had a reading comprehension problem obviously. Apparently behaviors are not attached during design time. So, that method won't get called. This question has a discussion about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154023/silverlight-blend-behaviors-do-not-get-attached-at-design-time